# Is there a way to get the URL that a link is scraped from?

Tags: scrapy

I've got a spider written out that crawls my website and scrapes a bunch of tags. I'm now trying to have it return the URL that the link was discovered on.

For example:

`www.example.com/product/123` was found on `www.example.com/page/2`.

When scrapy scrapes information from `/product/123` I want to have a field that is "Scraped From" and return `/page/2`. For every URL that is scraped, I'd want to find the originating page that the URL was found. I've been pouring over the docs and can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I updated my answer below. You should be able to get the previous URL by response.headers['Referer'] if not you can pass it in with meta. I would try the first method then the second.

Comment: I'll give that a shot right now. Thanks so much! I'm trying to do the other way as well. It would be cool to get the crawl path that it followed in order to arrive at a link. I'll keep you updated on how things go!

Comment: Doesn't look like referrer is included in the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the response.headers. There should be a referer header.

```
referer = response.headers['Referer']
```

You can also use meta to pass information along to the next URL.

```
def parse(self, response):
    product_url = response.css('#url').get()
    yield scrapy.Request(product_url, callback=self.parse_product, meta={'referer': response.url})

def parse_product(self, response):
    referer = response.meta['referer']
    item = ItemName()
    item['referer'] = referer
    yield item
```

Comment: Did exactly as you suggested. Worked like a charm. Ended up modifying it a bit so it records the entire crawl path.

Comment: Glad I could resolve the issue for you. But yeah you will find yourself in many situations where you need to pass things through meta. In this case you can get it from the headers, but often you will need to get tokens and other information and pass it along to the next request. Meta takes a dictionary and its where you pass any information you need in the next request.